# How do you delimit by "," instead of space in a TCL list?

Tags: list, tcl

So I've got a list, and in TCL the items are stored as {"1" "2" "3"}, space seperated. I'd like to convert this list to being {"1","2","3"} -- what would be an efficient way of doing this, aside from going through a foreach and lappending , to the end of each item?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't really make sense to me. In TCL, lists are stored internally as strings. When you say you want to list to {"1","2","3"}, I can only assume you are referring to the external display of the list. That can be done using the join command as follows:

```
% set x [list 1 2 3]
```

1 2 3

```
% set  z "\{\"[join $x "\","]\"\}"
```

{"1",2",3"}

Comment: Lists aren't stored as strings internally anymore, see Tcl_ListObject[link](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/ListObj.html) for example. But thats a minor detail.

Comment: That won't cope with doing all the quoting necessary to deal with the possibility of a `"` character, but that's when you get into doing the `foreach` (or farming it out a helper procedure).

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing string representation of a list with its in-memory representation. A list in memory is just that--an ordered list of otherwise disjoint elements. If you need to "pretty print" it (for output to a terminal, typically) make a string from it, and output it then.
The simplest way to make a string *in your case* is to use `[join]` as was already suggested.

In other words, don't be deceived by the fact that the code

```
set L [list 1 2 3]
puts $L
```

outputs "1 2 3": this does not mean that "a list is stored as a string with its elements space-separated". It's just the list's default string representation used by Tcl when you ask it to *implicitly* make a string out of a list by passing that list to `[puts]` which expects a string value. (*NB* strictly speaking, "expects a string value" is not correct with regards to the Tcl internals, but let's ignore this for now.)